# IntelliJ project where each module has it's own git repository

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am a new IntelliJ user (I've used Eclipse for many years). I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the-project-is-a-module concept in IntelliJ, since this does not hold true in Eclipse. The main issue I'm having is that I am using my top level package as the project in IntelliJ. I would like this top level package to be in a git repo. I would also like all the dependencies of this package to be in their own respetive git repos. When I check these packages out into my project, a do `git status` on the top level package, all of the dependencies show up in the untracked files. This behavior seems incorrect to me. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Edit:

To summarize the clarifications in the comments:

I would like to support hundreds of libraries any of which could change at a time. The dependency graph will also be frequently changing. For this reason, having one git repo or constantly updating .gitignore files is not maintainable.

Currently, I'm using Maven to manage dependencies but I'm open to using whatever is best suited for this job.

Finally, I would like to check out any library into my workspace and modify it and, if possible, have Intellij reflect my local changes when running code as if my local code were already built into the dependency graph. A type of local override if you will.

Comment: It seems to me it is more a git issue rather than an IntelliJ IDEA issue. Do you use git submodules ?

Comment: I've added git as a tag. I don't think git submodules are a good solution though. If possible, I would like to keep the git repositories completely separate, as I did in Eclipse. The nested nature of the git repos is completely arbitrary and only exists because Intellij enforces this.

Comment: Can you explain the reasons that you need each "module" in its own git repo?

Comment: You could add a .gitignore rules to exclude your dependencies from your top level package

Comment: I plan on having a large code base containing hundreds of packages and dozens of top-level packages. Obviously using a single git repo is not sustainable.

Comment: by "package" do you mean a Java package? What isn't sustainable about placing hundreds of Java packages in a single repo?

Comment: Sorry, by package I mean "module" or "library" not Java package. It is not sustainable to have hundreds of libraries in one git repo because you would have to check them all out at once, and many will not be related in any way.

Comment: If your libraries are changing so much for a single project, then maybe they aren't as general purpose as they should be.

Comment: Or maybe I'm working on a large team and constantly adding features?

Comment: Then you will need to use either submodules or a dependency management tool.

Comment: I should have noted that I'm using Maven.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ's directory structure places all of the modules in their parent project's directory. If you are developing libraries which are shared between several other projects, importing the library as a module is probably not the correct solution. Instead, you should treat each library as its own independent project and make "releases" using a build tool such as gradle or maven. Then your projects can treat the libraries the same way they do third-party libraries and use the build tool to import the library.

Comment: Many times, I want to edit my libraries specifically for use in a top-level package. This would make doing so impossibly cumbersome. I would have to create the library project, make the changes, build, switch windows, test in my top-level package, then go back to the library project to continue to iterate. Surely there must be some way of solving this problem. How do people with hundreds of packages use Intellij?